# Algorithm to add points at the edge of other points

Tags: algorithm

Let's say the initial map has only the red dots. Then I want to add all the green dots. Note that the shape is not always circular.

Any idea how to do that?

I was thinking to consider all as a cluster and then get the edge (or approximation) of the cluster and add new dots.

[image: t th]

Comment: You can build convex hull for the red point set, then expand it a bit.  *(If you don't want to make hull always convex, consider also alpha shapes)*

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quickhull

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm doing the quickhull approach for now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

One possibility that comes to mind would be to conmpute the convex hull polygon of the input, using one of the [known algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms) for that. Next, the center of gravity of the convex hull polygon could be used to shift the points of the convex hull outwards, resulting in a dilation of the boundary. If more points for the boundary are needed, one could interpolate between the points of the convex hull polygon.

Comment: Thanks, yes I'm doing the quickhull approach for now.